# What is the English term used for legal representation power?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, legalese

When someone assigns a lawyer to represent him or her, what do we call this document/certificate/letter/paper? Is it power of attorney? Procuration?

Let me explain the context in the following example:
I am a judge and there is a lawyer who wants to represent a client. I ask the lawyer to present something that proofs he has the right or power to do so.

So, what shall I, as a judge, ask the lawyer to provide to allow him or her to represent a client?

I hope I have made it clear.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. But lack of presentation of reasonable research is in itself a close-vote reason.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Being a judge, you are expected to *tell* us, not ask? No offense.

Comment: See also [law.se]

Answer (score 1):

You call it **"power/letter of attorney"** or **"proxy"** depending on context.

> - [**A power of attorney**](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/powerofattorney.asp) (POA) - is a legal document giving one person (the agent or attorney-in-fact) the power to act for another person (the principal). A person appointed as power of attorney is not necessarily an attorney.
> - [**Letter of Attorney**](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Letter+of+attorney) - A written instrument under seal, by which one or more persons, called the constituents, authorize one or more other persons called the attorneys, to do some lawful act by the latter, for or instead, and in the place of the former.
> - [**proxy**](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/proxy) - A person who is designated by another to represent that individual at a meeting or before a public body. **It also refers to the written authorization** allowing one person to act on behalf of another.

To answer your question, in court, a **"procuration"** as you mentioned or a **"letter of attorney"** will fit the bill.

Comment: Beware the pitfalls in legalese.